# ROS won't install on 14.04 (dependency hell)

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

I tried installing ROS on Ubuntu 14.04 using [this guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu).
When doing `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full` I get the following dependency error which results in a nightmare of dependcies as soon as I try to resolve them:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you run ´sudo apt-get install -f? It should try to resolve the problem itself, or at the very least tell us which packages.

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install -f' doesn't do anything. (nothing to isntall) and 'sudo apt-get install -f ros-indigo-desktop-full' produces the same output as above.

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem? did you manage to download it? please share if you did.

Comment: unfortunately not :( still the same problem

Comment: does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Checkout @Cerin's answer below, it helped me get further. (still installing)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too because I had some gazebo4 and gazebo5 packages installed. Unfortunately, Indigo only comes with gazebo2 and won't install if there are other gazebo packages already present.

Also, from [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/190177/how-to-install-ros-indigo-in-ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-bit/?answer=194764#post-id-194764), I had to install this one package first:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdformat1
```

After that, `ros-indigo-desktop-full` installed fine for me on 14.04.

Comment: Oh wow, I was VERY skeptical of this answer but what do you know, it worked for me too! Now to see if I can get rgbdslam installed...

Answer (score 0):

I tried with "aptitude" to resolve the dependency issue. Appear to be that some libraries need to be downgraded.

Comment: Could you please explain in a bit more detail which libraries needed to be downgraded and how you were able to resolve the dependency issue?